# What does $End_{R}(M)$ contain when $R $ is not commutative

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $M $ be a left module over a ring $R $ with idenitty.  If  $R $ is commutative,  we know that for every $r\in R $ ,$End_{R}(M)$ contains the function that sends $m $ to $rm $.

If $R $ is not commutative, then the only homomorphisms inside $End_{R}(M)$ that I can think of are the zero and identity maps.

Are there other natural examples of maps in  $End_{R}(M)$ thatI m not aware of ?

Is it possible that for a nontrivial pair of $M,R $ we have that $End_{R}(M)=\{0,1_{M}\}$

Thank you

Ok after Pedro s comment, I realize now that the endomorphism ring will also contain  the maps that send $m $ to $m+m $ and that send $m$ to $m+m+m $ and ........ I m still hoping to see more interesting maps

Comment: Any central element in $R$ induces an $R$-linear map as you stated, so at least $Z(R)$ is contained in $\operatorname{End}_R M$.

Comment: The notation becomes much more natural when you consider right $R$-modules instead of left $R$ modules. Then $R$ acts on $M$ on the right, and $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ acts on $M$ on the left. The condition for a homomorphism $f: M \to M$ of abelian groups to be an endomorphism of $M$ as a module becomes $f(mr) = (f(m)) r$, or $f(mr) = (fm)r$ if you omit the function notation - a kind of associativity condition. Since $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ is itself a ring, what we actually have is an $(\operatorname{End}_R(M), R)$ bimodule.

Comment: What does "nontrivial pair" here mean? Does $M=R$ and $End(R_R)\cong R$ count?

Comment: @rschwieb  I know the term trivial is vague here. I left it open so may be I can see interesting examples from people here. But after all,  I know my question is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F = \mathbb F_p$ for $p$ a prime number, and let $$R = 
\begin{pmatrix}* & * & \cdots & * \\
               0 & * & \cdots & * \\
               \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
               0 & 0 & \cdots & *\end{pmatrix}$$ be the ring of upper triangular matrices with entries in $F$ (of some fixed size). $R$ acts on $$M = \begin{pmatrix} * \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ in the natural way. We have $\operatorname{End}_R(M) = F$. Since $\mathbb Z \twoheadrightarrow F$, it follows that the endomorphisms of $M$ consist only of those of the form $m \mapsto m+ m + \cdots + m$.

Does that meet your criterion of "nontrivial"?